# Where did the quote or study of developers write 10 lines of code per day come from?

Tags: productivity, metrics, research

When I search the internet people said there was a 'study' that says developers write 10 lines of code per day come. Other results claim the mythical man month says it. I searched a digital copy of the book and didn't find it. Is this quote made up and went viral? If it was real what year/system/language/hardware were the participants using?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month

Comment: Sorry about the last link.  For the WIKI link above at the bottom page are the references which contains a PDF version of the 1975 edition.  On page 4, The Tarpit there is this line: "And every programmer
is prepared to believe such tales, for he knows that he could build
any program much faster than the 1000 statements/year reported
for industrial teams." which roughly equates to 10 lines a day.  Although not directly said, it is inferred this is where the metric came from.

Comment: If you have ever worked in an industry or for a specific boss that cannot make up it's mind, redoing something over and over, throwing it away when laws or customers change I can absolutely believe that the *productive output* in a year is 10 lines a day. The developer may have written 100s of lines a day just to get to that output though. Personally, I find that style frustrating and cannot understand how it is economically viable, but there are enough people, bosses and developers, who take part in that style of developing solutions.

Comment: To quote a funny t-shirt about this method: "With just four to five weeks of development, you can save *hours* of planning".

Comment: There's the famous "minus 2000 lines of code" anecdote: https://www.folklore.org/Negative_2000_Lines_Of_Code.html from the author of the original Apple Quickdraw.

Comment: On some of my most productive days, my net LOC produced is negative.

Answer (score 7):

In Brooks' MMM, he tackles the issue in chapter 8, "Calling the Shot". He doesn't explicitly say "10 lines a day" so far as I can see, but it's apparent from the various data he quotes that he is talking about LoC/men/days being a single or double digit figure.

LoC/man/day is not really a good guide for how much code a particular person writes on a particular day, but it sounds a plausible long-term workforce average to me.

There are always questions about what counts as a line, but the choice of language is not found to make a huge difference.

I wouldn't dwell on trying to reconcile an exact figure with your own experience or make sense of all the caveats and the different things that are averaged out.

The real takeaway for software managers is that computer code really is enormously expensive to produce, and that code length is very closely related to complexity (as perceived by developers).

Shorn of any routine boilerplate, and once you include (as I believe Brooks does) the overheads of management, communication, analysis, and the reproduction of context-specific knowledge that sometimes occurs at some distance in time from the actual writing of code but is a necessary precursor for it (for example, training, technical investigations, devising patterns and algorithms of general use, etc.), then I can certainly well believe that it costs a business on average a full man-week of staff resource to get 50 lines of code written.

Meanwhile, measuring a programmer on a daily basis by LoC, is about as absurd as asking a non-technical manager to carry a microphone and measuring him by how many instructions he gives or words he speaks.

Comment: just reading that chapter and I cant make any of the figures given work out at 10 loc per day. Only one of the studies even uses lines! all the rest are in statements

Comment: @Ewan, I couldn't myself see the quote verbatim, or (purely at a glance) see any simple arithmetic to find 10 LoC/man/day. Many figures are quoted in years, so you'd have to reckon working days, minus holidays, and I gave up on the mental arithmetic. But "1200 LoC per man year" (as an example of a figure Brooks does quote) seems roughly equivalent to 10 LoC/man/day (as distinct from 100 or 1,000 LoC/man/day).

Comment: What about hardware? Were these statements using punch cards? Because that would definitely affect my productivity

Comment: @AndrewSpar, I don't think it makes much difference, because each era has its ways of balancing the situation so that the developer's job is back to being difficult and subtle enough that it takes a day to produce ten lines. If punch cards imposed serious overheads, you'd just have the programmer hand-write and delegate the punching to a clerk.

Answer (score 4):

OK I think it comes from The Mythical Man Month, page 4, The Tar Pit

> And every programmer is prepared to believe such tales, for he knows
> that he could build any program much faster than the 1000
> statements/year reported for industrial teams.

I found these lecture notes : [https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/man.month.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Eparrt/course/601/lectures/man.month.html) where the line has been noted as :

> A program is just a set of instructions that seems to do what you
> want. All programmers say "Oh, I can easily beat the 10 lines / day
> cited by industrial programmers." They are talking about just coding
> something, not building a product.

I think what probably happened was that the line was updated when lecturing to make more sense to modern students who would be more used to "lines of code" as a measure rather than statements.

If you read the chapter "Calling the Shot" where he goes into some studies on actual productivity measurements they don't seem to align with this figure. So its not clear that it comes from any actual research, but was perhaps just a  figure bandied about in management circles.

Comment: 3 statements per line? Are they all for loops?

Comment: I think hes talking about assembly, so yeah maybe all ifs and loops and pushes etc

Answer (score 1):

The year, the system, the language and the hardware are mostly irrelevant. The more interesting question is, is that number (or order of magnitude) plausible?

- Take a small project with one or two people working on it, and you will usually get 100-400 lines of tested and debugged code per day per person (including code for tests, assuming a normal 8-hour working day, not some 48-hour hackathon). That's my personal observation (ignoring cowboy coders who will surely brag that they are a lot faster - but I wrote "tested and debugged", don't forget that!).
- The more people you add to a project or product development organization, the fewer lines of code per day per developer will be achieved, due to the organizational overhead (still the total number of lines of code per day will usually increase assuming that the project is managed properly). You can probably generate any number you like just by picking the correct project - 10 lines of code / day / developer, or fewer.
- For example, here is a rough estimate for the Windows 10 Operating System from some numbers I googled. Windows 10 has roughly 50 million lines of code, and about 4000 contributors to the code. It was developed (starting with Win NT) over a period of about 30 years. So 50 million / 4000 / 30 years gives about 417 lines of code per developer per year (!), which means, for a year with 250 working days, fewer than 2 lines of code / day / developer.

So, I am sure you will find many projects with 10 LOC / day / developer. You only have to pick the right project size.

Comment: *"100-400 lines ... ignoring some cowboy coders which will surely brag they are a lot faster"* - I like to brag I'm a lot slower than that!

Answer (score -1):

Another source might be the COCOMO models; they're careful never to do that final division, but if you take the output of any of the examples (or real projects) in COCOMO and work out the corresponding LoC/dev/day, it's about that...